# How should I write a handler class for this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, class, before-trigger

I try to write a trigger handler to this trigger (in order to write test to this trigger), but I don't know how it should be done.
This is my trigger:

```
trigger FinancialTrigger on DU_ListedFinancialService__c (before insert) {

    for (FinancialTrigger __c f: Trigger.new) {
        if (trigger.isInsert) {
            f.financialCost__c = f.financialCostField2__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a trigger this simple, you should really consider using a formula field instead. Failing that, a before-save record triggered flow would give you a bit more power. Both options would not require writing tests.

Comment: Can I set a value from formula field to Text field using formula? (I need to use Text field)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your situation is here (you should [edit] your question to provide additional details, don't add them as a comment). Looking at things again, it appears that you're trying to set a text field once (at record creation) and _only once_. If that's correct, that's information that you should have included in your question (questions should focus on the overall problem you're trying to solve instead of shoehorning in a previously chosen solution.) You could use a before-save record triggered flow to copy a formula field into a text field to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level, creating a trigger handler is just:

1. Create an Apex class
2. Copy/paste the code from your trigger into this new class (and then delete the code from your trigger)

The big selling point of trigger frameworks in general is that they add a layer of indirection.

Your trigger calls your framework
Your framework calls your handler
Your handler runs the actual code

This is what you'll see if you look at some of the common frameworks like [Kevin O'Hara's](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) or [Chris Aldridge's](https://github.com/ChrisAldridge/Lightweight-Trigger-Framework).

Given a trigger like this

```java
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c(before insert, after insert, before update, after update){
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        for(MyObject__c instance :Trigger.new){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

The trigger using a framework looks something like

```java
// This is a simplified example, and is not representative of all frameworks
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c(before insert, after insert, before update, after update){
    MyFramework.run(new MyHandler(Trigger.old, Trigger.new), Trigger.operationType);
}
```

And your handler would look something like

```java
// Again, a simplified and incomplete example
// This is not meant to be copy/pasted, it's meant to illustrate what the handler you'll
//   write will probably resemble
public class MyHandler implements MyFramework.Handler{
    public void onBeforeInsert(List<SObject> newList){
        // I hope it's clear that this for loop was copy/pasted from the original trigger
        //   (with a small change to the list we're looping over with the
        //   for loop. We don't want to use Trigger Context Variables directly)
        // The check for the trigger context (before insert, after update, etc...) is
        //   not required because the framework you're using is probably routing
        //   requests to the appropriate handler/method/class (such as this
        //   "onBeforeInsert" method) auotmatically.

        // In other words, the framework does that work for you, and you can focus
        //   on the code that actually _does_ something useful
        for(MyObject__c instance :(List<MyObject__c>)newList){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

You *can* write tests for triggers, but the only way to execute a trigger is by using DML (which means that *all* of the logic contained within the trigger is executed).

The additional indirection allows you to test logic directly, isolated from other logic, and without DML. It's that "isolated from other logic" bit that's the most important, and it's why it's worth it to go through the trouble of using a framework.